c# MVC con Net 8, Descarga de zip MemoryStream
Estimados tengo la siguiente problemática, y ver si alguien me puede ayuda con resolverla, no se si es un problema de Net 8 o es que hay algo mal en algún lugar que no reconozco.
Tengo un Controlador que contiene solo un método ActionResult que recibe un modelo, el modelo es el formulario actual que contiene una serie de datos los que son pasados al método del controlador correctamente y cuando se presiona el botón Descargar que llama a DownloadConfig() del controlador.
Estos datos los dividos en dos partes, cada parte la convierto en un archivo .json, el primer archivo lo llamo file1.json y file2.json.
Luego una vez que le asigno contenido a cada uno, los Zipeo y luego intento descargar hacia el cliente. Para asegurarme que el zip esta bien, primero lo grabo en el disco del host y al revisarlo esta correctamente generado lo puedo abrir sin problemas. (He intentado abrir el archivo generado en el disco y me da el mismo problema, por lo que supongo el problema esta entre el controlador y el browser)
Desde el controlador envió los bytes[] al browser, para ser descargado como archivo, pero al revisar la descarga el archivo esta corrupto.
Y ese es mi problema, no se si es problema de la versión de .Net 8 les dejo el código para que puedan ver que podría estar haciendo mal. O saber si hay alguien mas con el mismo problemas.
Saludos y gracias de ante mano!!
Controlador:
namespace XenXauroCode.Areas.Cliente.Controllers
{
    public class ConfiguradorController : BaseController
    {
        // GET: ConfiguradorController
        public ActionResult Index()
        {


            return View();
        }


        [HttpGet("GenerateFrase")]
        public IActionResult GenerateFrase()
        {
            // Lógica para generar el string
            string generatedString = "hfskhdf9074357"; // Reemplaza esto con tu lógica de generación
            return Ok(generatedString);
        }

        [HttpGet("GenerateSal")]
        public IActionResult GenerateSal()
        {
            // Lógica para generar el string
            string generatedString = "172hdm03mdla"; // Reemplaza esto con tu lógica de generación
            return Ok(generatedString);
        }

        [HttpGet("GenerateVector")]
        public IActionResult GenerateVector()
        {
            // Lógica para generar el string
            string generatedString = "s3cr3t012345"; // Reemplaza esto con tu lógica de generación
            return Ok(generatedString);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadConfig([FromBody] ParametroConexionVM model)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string fileName = $"XauroConfiguraciones_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.zip";

                    // Generar los JSON de los objetos
                    var secretsJson = GenerateSecretsJson(model);
                    var configJson = GenerateConfigJson(model);

                    // Crear y retornar el archivo ZIP
                    var zipFile = CreateZipFile(secretsJson, configJson);

                    // Guardar el archivo ZIP en el servidor para verificar que no este corrupto
                    //
                    using (var zipToCreate = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        zipToCreate.Write(zipFile, 0, zipFile.Length);
                    }
                    return File(zipFile, "application/zip", fileName);

                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error al generar el archivo de configuración." });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Manejo de excepciones: Registrar el error y retornar un mensaje de error al cliente
                Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error al generar el archivo ZIP: {ex.Message}");
                return StatusCode(500, "Ocurrió un error al generar el archivo ZIP. Por favor, intente nuevamente.");
            }
        }


        #region Métodos privados
        // Método para generar el JSON de los secretos
        private string GenerateSecretsJson(ParametroConexionVM model)
        {
            var secrets = new Parametros
            {
                Frase = model.Frase,
                Salt = model.Sal,
                Algorit = model.Algoritmo,
                Iteraciones = model.Iteraciones,
                Vector = model.Vector,
                TamanoClave = model.TamanoClave
            };
            secrets.Guardar();

            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(secrets);
        }

        // Método para generar el JSON de la configuración
        private string GenerateConfigJson(ParametroConexionVM model)
        {
            var config = new XenCfg.Config
            {
                Adonet = new Adonet
                {
                    Proveedor = model.Provider,
                    Encriptado = false
                },
                Server = new Server
                {
                    Nombre = (EncriptacionPlus
                    .Encrypt(model.Server
                    , ParametrosClave.Frase
                    , ParametrosClave.Salt
                    , ParametrosClave.Algorit
                    , ParametrosClave.Iteraciones
                    , ParametrosClave.Vector
                    , ParametrosClave.TamanoClave)),
                    Puerto = (EncriptacionPlus
                    .Encrypt(model.Port.ToString()
                    , ParametrosClave.Frase
                    , ParametrosClave.Salt
                    , ParametrosClave.Algorit
                    , ParametrosClave.Iteraciones
                    , ParametrosClave.Vector
                    , ParametrosClave.TamanoClave)),
                    Encriptado = true
                },
                Database = new Database
                {
                    Nombre = EncriptacionPlus
                    .Encrypt(model.Database
                    , ParametrosClave.Frase
                    , ParametrosClave.Salt
                    , ParametrosClave.Algorit
                    , ParametrosClave.Iteraciones
                    , ParametrosClave.Vector
                    , ParametrosClave.TamanoClave),
                    Encriptado = true
                },
                User = new User
                {
                    Nombre = EncriptacionPlus
                    .Encrypt(model.User
                    , ParametrosClave.Frase
                    , ParametrosClave.Salt
                    , ParametrosClave.Algorit
                    , ParametrosClave.Iteraciones
                    , ParametrosClave.Vector
                    , ParametrosClave.TamanoClave),
                    Encriptado = true
                },
                Password = new Password
                {
                    Secreto = EncriptacionPlus
                    .Encrypt(model.Password
                    , ParametrosClave.Frase
                    , ParametrosClave.Salt
                    , ParametrosClave.Algorit
                    , ParametrosClave.Iteraciones
                    , ParametrosClave.Vector
                    , ParametrosClave.TamanoClave),
                    Encriptado = true
                }
            };

            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(config);
        }

        // Método para crear el archivo ZIP
        private byte[] CreateZipFile(string secretsJson, string configJson)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    // Agregar el archivo secrets.json
                    var secretsEntry = archive.CreateEntry("secrets.json");
                    using (var entryStream = secretsEntry.Open())
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(secretsJson);
                    }

                    // Agregar el archivo config.json
                    var configEntry = archive.CreateEntry("ConfigAccess.json");
                    using (var entryStream = configEntry.Open())
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(configJson);
                    }
                }

                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                byte[] bytesStream = memoryStream.ToArray();
                return bytesStream;
            }

        }
        #endregion

    }
}

Vista, el script asociado al boton
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Llamada AJAX para el botón download
            $('#download').click(function () {
                var model = {
                    Provider: $('#provider').val(),            // Coincide con 'Provider' en C#
                    Server: $('#server').val(),               // Coincide con 'Server' en C#
                    Port: parseInt($('#port').val()),         // Coincide con 'Port' en C#
                    Database: $('#database').val(),           // Coincide con 'Database' en C#
                    User: $('#user').val(),                   // Coincide con 'User' en C#
                    Password: $('#password').val(),           // Coincide con 'Password' en C#
                    PasswordConfirm: $('#passwordconfirm').val(), // Coincide con 'PasswordConfirm' en C#
                    Frase: $('#frase').val(),                 // Coincide con 'Frase' en C#
                    Sal: $('#sal').val(),                     // Coincide con 'Sal' en C#
                    Algoritmo: $('#algoritmo').val(),         // Coincide con 'Algoritmo' en C#
                    Iteraciones: parseInt($('#iteraciones').val()), // Coincide con 'Iteraciones' en C#
                    Vector: $('#vector').val(),               // Coincide con 'Vector' en C#
                    TamanoClave: parseInt($('#tamanoclave').val()) // Coincide con 'TamanoClave' en C#
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DownloadConfig", "Configurador")', // URL de la acción en tu controlador
                    type: 'POST',                                   // Método HTTP POST
                    contentType: 'application/json',                // Especifica que estás enviando JSON
                    data: JSON.stringify(model),                    // Convierte el objeto `model` a JSON
                    success: function (data) {
                        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/zip' });
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.download = 'XauroConfiguracion.zip';
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click(); // Desencadena la descarga del archivo
                        document.body.removeChild(link);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error(xhr.responseText); // Muestra cualquier error en la consola para depuración
                        alert('Error al descargar el archivo.');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}

